# Thinkpad X1Carbon randomly freezes with Ubuntu20.04

Tags: 20.04, freeze, thinkpad, system

I had a Thinkpad X1carbon Gen8 with Ubuntu 20.04 installed. Most of the time the system works well, but randomly freezes (even `ctrl+alt+F3` does not work and I have to physically reboot the system).

Any suggestions to diagnose the problem or how to fix it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I have the same notebook. Have you seen a pattern for when your ThinkPad freezes? It is after waking from suspend, when watching videos, or something else?

Comment: For most of time, I only suspend but not shut down the machine. So it should come from waking from suspend, it typically happens after running for a while.